# How to pass a list of arguments to python command

Tags: python

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the app')
skill_list = utils.read_yaml_file('skill_list.yml')
parser.add_argument('skill', choices=skill_list, help="Which skill?")

parser.add_argument('endpoints', default=None, help="Configuration file for the connectors as a yml file")

skill = parser.parse_args().skill
endpoints = parser.parse_args().endpoints
```

In the above code, I can pass two parameters to as follows:

```
run.py joke endpoints.yml
```

If my 'skill' is a variable list, meaning that I don't know how much arguments users might pass. In such a case, I can do:

```
run.py joke command weather endpoints.yml
```

Here "joke command weather" will be passed by the 'skill' argument. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: @MasonCaiby how to use args with the "add_argument" method?

Comment: Can you use an option like `-e endpoints.yml` or does it need to be always the last argument?

Comment: Ah, I see... can you use this? `parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')` see the argparse docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to provide [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) parameter in `add_argument` function.

```
parser.add_argument('--skill', nargs='+', help='List of skills', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--endpoints', default=None, help="Configuration file for the connectors as a yml file", required=True)

# Usage
# python run.py --skill joke command weather --endpoints endpoints.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to use `-foo` or `--foo` for your endpoints. But If u want exactly same passing order of arguments. This should work

```
parser.add_argument('skill', choices=skill_list, help="Which skill?", nargs='+')

parser.add_argument('endpoints', default=None, help="Configuration file for the connectors as a yml file")
```